# Dynamic printing with javascript - building a string with various conditional components

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get rid of the comma right after the input firstAuthorInitials.value.slice(0,1) only when it is empty.
In case when in the input firstAuthorInitials.value.slice(0,1) is something written the code works fine.

The code looks like:

```js
if (edition.value == "none") {
 div.innerHTML += 
  firstAuthorSurname.value + ", " + 
  firstAuthorName.value.slice(0, 1) + "." + 
  firstAuthorInitials.value.slice(0,1) + "."  + ", " +
  year.value + 
  ". <i>" + title.value + "</i>. " + 
  placeOfPublication.value + ": " + 
  publisher.value + ".";

}
```

Comment: This question is in need of a more specific title.

Comment: Well, check if empty, add condition(s), and continue with concatenation? Shouldn't be big problem?

Comment: You might try a [*conditional expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like `... + (firstAuthorInitials.value.length? 'foo' : 'bar') + ...`.

Comment: In this case I would have to change it in so many conditions, is there any other way to get it?

Comment: @RobG how would the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array, push things into it, then join. Use logic applied to each element to decide if you want to push it or not.

```js
if (edition.value == "none") {
 var stringComponents = [];

 stringComponents.push(
  firstAuthorSurname.value, 
  ", ", 
  firstAuthorName.value.slice(0, 1),
  "."
 );
 
 if (/* some kind of logic */) {
  stringComponents.push(firstAuthorInitials.value.slice(0,1), "., ");
 }
 
 stringComponents.push(
  year.value + 
  ". <i>",
  title.value,
  "</i>. ",
  placeOfPublication.value,
  ": ",
  publisher.value,
  "."
 );
 
 div.innerHTML += stringComponents.join("");
}
```